# Which is the better way to write log statements

Tags: java, string, logging, slf4j

JAVA Logging:

Which is the better way to write log statements:
1. `log.info("Value1 : {} Value2:{} Value3:{}",new Object[]{a,b,c};`
Or
2. `log.info(String.format("Value1 : %s Value2:%s Value3:%s",a,b,c));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefer the first one.

If no log is written because your log level is higher than `info` then you have the cost of the call to `log.info` and the construction of the temporary parameter array. But the logger will not construct the log string.

In the second case you have the call plus the formatting of the log string which is likely more time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

There's no better or worse way. Both will give you the same output. However I suggest using slf4j (with logback provider for example). With such configuration you could log in this way:

```
log.info("{} {} {}", a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to write is to pass the values into the logger. The logger's info() or debug() takes variable arguments. Assuming that you are using log4j or slj4j or logback as library. If you have not decided, seriously consider logback.

The right way to  write will be as follows.

```
log.info("Value1 :{} Value2: {} Value3: {}", a, b, c);
```

You need not create a string object explicitly. This is handle internally by the logging framework.

If there is specific processing of the object just for logging, write logging after checking isDebugEnabled(), so in a production system, this will not be processed.